# Get Login user details in laravel resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am using laravel framework. I am using laravel passport for authentication. I have to check whether the user is logged in or not and then add favorite field if the user has liked that particular product. I have binded the data using resources. I am unable to find the user who is logged in since Auth::id() always returns false in resource. Is there any way to access Auth::id() in resource too?

Comment: Simply use `\Auth::user()->id()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

```
// Get the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();
```

Comment: Actually i have to get the user who has logged in in the roue which does not require any authentication. I found the solution! Thankyu anyway :)

Comment: my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can access id by using `\Auth::user()->id()` before using it first check Auth in condition using `\Auth::check()`.